# Victory Stacked Area giving undefined on tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

I'm using victory stacked area chart and trying to display label on tool tip. But whenever I'm clicking on chart it's not giving index. I tried to console it and it gives `undefined` to index value but it working fine in stacked bar chart I used the same code. It's working stacked bar chart but not on stacked area chart. Below is my code

```
const clickEvent = [
    {
      target: 'data',
      mutation: (props: {
        data: {
          [x: string]: {
            x: React.SetStateAction<string>;
            y: React.SetStateAction<number>;
          };
        };
        index: number;
      }) => {
        ({
          style: {fill: colors.primeColor, width: 14.5},
        });
        console.log(props);
        setDay(props?.data[props.index]?.x);
        setWasteItem(props?.data[props.index]?.y);
      },
    },
    {
      target: 'labels',
      mutation: () => ({active: false}),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <VictoryChart
      theme={VictoryTheme.material}
      height={300}
      containerComponent={<VictoryVoronoiContainer />}
      width={380}>
      <VictoryStack height={200}>
        <VictoryArea
          style={{
            data: {
              fill: colors.orangeOpacity02,
              stroke: colors.orange,
              strokeWidth: 2,
            },
          }}
          data={wastedData}
          labelComponent={
            <VictoryTooltip
              renderInPortal={false}
              style={{fill: colors.orange}}
            />
          }
          labels={() => `${day}: ${wasteItem} Wasted`}
          events={[
            {
              target: 'data',
              eventHandlers: {
                onPressIn: () => {
                  return clickEvent;
                },
              },
            },
          ]}
        />
        <VictoryArea
          style={{
            data: {
              fill: colors.primeColorOpacity05,
              stroke: colors.primeColor,
              strokeWidth: 2,
            },
          }}
          data={usedData}
          labelComponent={
            <VictoryTooltip
              renderInPortal={false}
              style={{fill: colors.primeColor}}
            />
          }
          labels={() => `${day}: ${wasteItem} Used`}
          events={[
            {
              target: 'data',
              eventHandlers: {
                onPressIn: () => {
                  return clickEvent;
                },
              },
            },
          ]}
        />
      </VictoryStack>
      <VictoryAxis
        fixLabelOverlap={true}
        tickValues={['Aug 1', 'Aug 15', 'Aug 30']}
        style={{
          axis: {stroke: 'transparent'},
          grid: {stroke: 'transparent'},
          tickLabels: {
            fontSize: 12,
            paddingLeft: 10,
          },
        }}
      />
      <VictoryAxis
        dependentAxis
        tickValues={[0, 10, 20, 30]}
        orientation="left"
        style={{
          tickLabels: {fontSize: 12},
          axis: {stroke: 'transparent'},
        }}
      />
    </VictoryChart>
  );
};
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in that code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no key called `data` in the event's prop.

> eventHandlers should be given as an object whose keys are standard
> event names (e.g., onClick) and whose values are event callbacks.
> Callbacks are called with the props of the individual element that
> triggered the event. For example, when a click event occurs on a bar,
> the props object supplied to the onClick handler will include props
> specific to that individual bar, such as `datum`, `index`, `style`, etc.
> Return values from event handler callbacks may be used to mutate other
> elements.

you can use `datum`